# react-router-dom package does not include <Switch>

Tags: reactjs

[Route imported from react-router-dom[][Switch is not being imported from react-router-dom]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3oas.png)

Comment: Please give us more details and clarify what's wrong here. Also, don't post code as images.

Comment: What is the version of your react-router-dom ?

Answer (score 0):

react-router-dom had a major update (v6) a little time ago. They have replaced `Switch` component with `Routes`.
Read more - https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5